# How to change colour of reference counts next to definitions

Tags: colorscheme, plugin-coc, nvim

I'm using CoC with the elm-language-server, and I've found that for each top level definition, at the end of the line I have an extra annotation printed that gives a reference count and whether it's exposed or local to the module:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, this is printed in the same colour as regular variables, which is quite distracting. So I'd like to change the colour, but I'm unsure of the term for this feature or how to refer to this info text.

I'm guessing that if I knew the category that this text falls under I could change something in my colour scheme to affect it? But of course I can't even place my cursor on it to inspect its syntax category, since it's not part of the text buffer itself. Or would it be a setting within CoC?

#### Edit

I've found out that this is called **Code Lens**, and I've found [this page about changing the colour of CoC's Code Lens](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/y6rh9lzhnv-change-the-codelens-annotation-color-in-coc).

If I enter eg. `hi CocCodeLens ctermfg=243` as an ex command in an open Elm file, this works fine, but putting it in my .vimrc, after I set my colour scheme and after CoC aliases, it has no effect. Why would this be?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!